# Hiding/Obfuscating reactjs code of .jsx file type?

Tags: reactjs, obfuscation, jsx

So, I've been making some research browsing throught net and checking websites that are in react and I've noticed that at 80% of them I can't reach their react code anyway to check how it is written. Does people hidden it somewhere or somehow? Because I just been putting my at the bottom of body closure and it is very visible and easily accessable.

How can I hide code of react? Or make it hard to find/read? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

JSX is not html, and browsers display it. JSX is a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) that gets compiled to JS by babel. According to React's [JSX docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

> Fundamentally, JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the
>   React.createElement(component, props, ...children) function.

So this code:

```
<MyButton color="blue" shadowSize={2}>
  Click Me
</MyButton>
```

compiles into:

```
React.createElement(
  MyButton,
  {color: 'blue', shadowSize: 2},
  'Click Me'
)
```